# Git credentials catche issue

Tags: git, github, git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

Thanks to [git disabling support for weak cahcing](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/), I am having issue with caching credentials. I updated to latest git for window ( 2.18 ) but the issue persists.

Apparantly, the windows Credentials manager is being used for credentials storage instead for GCM for windows. Because everytime it prompts for credentials, a new entry is created -
[image]

and it stops prompting for credentials. However when I delete it, it goes back to prompting for credentials.

I am getting the following issue while the credentials is cache. 
[image]

I guess, things might work if I change the credendial manager to GCM for windows. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Git credential manager for Windows is an executable that prompts for credentials and stores them in the Windows credential manager, so they work in tandem. It sounds like you are already using this setup, and your issue is not to do with the credential caching.

You can change the way this works in config though, e.g.

```
git config credential.helper manager
```

Or

```
git config credential.helper wincred
```